# How to put players in a specific spot on joining the game?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to make a kit pvp map, and when players enter the game they are supposed to spawn on a floating platform, but they just spawn where they left the game last.

If a player dies they spawn at the right spot, but not when they enter the game.

Also, is there anyway to change the direction you point in when you spawn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a new objective that tracks when the game has been quit:

   /scoreboard objectives add GameQuit stat.leaveGame
2. On a redstone block clock, have these two commands in this order:

   tp @a[score_GameQuit_min=1] X Y Z XROT YROT

   scoreboard players set @a[score_GameQuit_min=1] GameQuit 0

[image]

Replace X Y Z with the coordinates you want the player to log in on, and XROT YROT with the rotation you want them to log in on.

Comment: Thanks! Do I just build the picture exactly, commands and all, or otherwise? @colorfusion

Comment: @ArtiSchmidt Building it exactly as pictured should work, although make sure to replace "X Y Z XROT YROT" with the coordinates and rotation you want. Also use F3 to make sure that positive X (east) is in the direction of the arrow on the picture.

Comment: Ok, so build what it shows in the picture, but do I use the commands in the picture or in your answer? And all the command should have / in front of them right? @colorfusion

Comment: @ArtiSchmidt The commands in the picture and in my answer are the same ones. Follow what I say in the answer: Run the add objective command, then build the clock (shown in the picture). A "/" doesn't matter in command blocks.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. I made sure it was pointed towards positive x. I put the "new objective in a command block a few blocks away from the clock, was I supposed to put it in a command block? I'm new to this so I don't know a lot of things about it. By the way, I did use slashes in the command blocks. @colorfusion

Comment: @ArtiSchmidt Running the "new objective" command in chat is easier; you could put it in a command block I suppose, but you only need to activate it once. Try breaking one of the redstone blocks, if you've set the clock up correctly then it should immediately reappear.